# Attach callback function to RenderEditable’s onCaretChanged

Tags: flutter, dart, callback, textfield

After traversing the `RenderObject` tree of a `TextField`, I have a reference to the underlying `RenderEditable`. `RenderEditable` has a property called `onCaretChanged` that will fire the attached callback function every time the cursor/caret moves.

If I were constructing a `RenderEditable` from scratch, I would understand how to attach my callback function in the constructor, but I now only have a reference to it after it has been made in the Build function. How can I attach a callback function to this object after the fact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like after a recent Flutter update (v3.13.0) `onCaretChanged` has been removed. Instead, the way to go about this is to attach a void callback to the `TextEditingController` with `addListener` (which gives text and caret changes) and utilize the `RenderEditable` function [`getLocalRectForCaret`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderEditable/getLocalRectForCaret.html).